# Handling DATETIME and DATE for Start and End dates

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a table that holds information about when a person is on leave. The two key fields are are:

**SQL

```
StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
EndDate DATE NULL
```

Within my .Net code, these are stored as `DateTime` types.

So, if a user has holiday from 13th of August, until 13th of August, thats 1 days leave. The dates should be inclusive, with the Start being at 0:00 (Midnight), and then EndDate being 23:59.59 basically.

So, depending on if it's Start, or End, they're treated slightly differently.

My system works with whole days. i.e. DATE values. I don't use Time at all, but am forced to because of the DateTime type in .Net. But they're all set to midnight when reading from the database.

The code I am focusing on, that isn't working, is this:

```
public string AvailableToday
    {
        get
        {
            if (NonAvailibility != null)
            {
                var i = NonAvailibility.FirstOrDefault(t => DateTime.UtcNow <= t.EndDate && DateTime.UtcNow >= t.StartDate);
                if (i != null) return i.NonAvailibilityType ;
                return "";
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

The point of that code, is to return the reason for the person not being available today. If the person IS available, I should return an empty string.

The problem is, my user that I am testing with, has leave fromthe 12th of August, to the 13th of August.

That should be two full days. But because `DateTime.UtcNow` returns the current date with time, and we're into the 13th now... the code is saying that he is not on leave today.

A fix may be to just add one day to the EndDate value? So, instead of 12th of Aug to the 13th of Aug, it will check from the 12th of Aug, to the 14th midnight. That seems hacky, but may be my only solution. Or, truncate the `DateTime.UtcNow` to set it to midnight, and then change the check to:

```
t => DateTime.UtcNow <= t.EndDate && SetToMidnight(DateTime.UtcNow) >= t.StartDate
```

(Or, instead of using that 'SetToMidnight....', just use DateTime.UtcNow.Date)

Is there a better way to handle this solution, or do I need to do one of the above possible solutions?

(Note, TimeZones and all that is being handled in another question)
10th

Comment: Could you not use `ToShortDateString()` in order to get only the Date portion without the time?

Comment: @Edper, I think that's more for display, and then you have to do string compare. TO remove the time portion, I think DateTime.UtcNow.Date does the job, which returns a date without the time factor. Well, it does have a time, but it's midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try DateTime.UtcNow.Date

```
public string AvailableToday
{
    get
    {
        if (NonAvailibility != null)
        {
            var i = NonAvailibility.FirstOrDefault(t => DateTime.UtcNow.Date <= t.EndDate && DateTime.UtcNow.Date >= t.StartDate);
            if (i != null) return i.NonAvailibilityType ;
            return "";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Note, this only works if `EndDate` and `StartDate` do not have a time portion to them. I know they don't in this case, but it is a important fact to know if someone else uses this code in the future (or he changes his schema to use `datetime` instead of `date` in the database). However just throwing `.Date` on `StartTime` and `EndTime` would fix that too (again not needed here, but if you do ever store times, you will need it)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem before and you will find that 
`t => DateTime.UtcNow <= t.EndDate` doens't work perfectly ,so i added `+1` to the end date in order to make it work,also you can make your fields in database to `DateTime` instead of `Date` only,it's better to keep the variable in "code" and "database" same type

1. Change your database type to DateTime
2. I solved this issue like you said by adding +1 to end date